# spring-boot security share session by redis

Tags: spring, session, spring-boot, spring-security, redis

I have a spring-boot security demo,I want to share session with redis.I add some code to pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and new one redis config class

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class RedisSessionConfig {
    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<Object, Object> sessionRedisTemplate(
            RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        RedisTemplate<Object, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setKeySerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
        template.setHashKeySerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
        template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        return template;
    }
}
```

add param to 'application.properties' file.

```
spring.session.store-type=redis
# redis database
spring.redis.database=8
# redis host
spring.redis.host=102.128.2.65
# redis password
#spring.redis.password=
#redis port
spring.redis.port=6379
```

the program can startup as before.and I can find some spring message in the redis.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xk8WK.png)

It's wrong when login success.I find spring security put the SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper$HttpSessionWrapper to session with the session key 'SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT' when login success .
why? The HttpSessionWrapper class is a spring's inner class.why spring put it to redis and did't serialized?
I don't know how to fix this problem.please help me ,thanks very much.

The error log：

```
20:25:17.629 [http-nio-8099-exec-6] ERROR o.s.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter - Forwarding to error page from request [/login] due to exception [Cannot serialize; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception is java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper$HttpSessionWrapper]
    org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Cannot serialize; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception is java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper$HttpSessionWrapper
        at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.serialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:93)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.rawHashValue(AbstractOperations.java:171)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultHashOperations.putAll(DefaultHashOperations.java:129)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultBoundHashOperations.putAll(DefaultBoundHashOperations.java:86)
        at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository$RedisSession.saveDelta(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:770)
        at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository$RedisSession.access$000(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:662)
        at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.save(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:388)
        at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.save(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:245)
        at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.commitSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:245)
        at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.access$100(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:217)
        at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:170)
        at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:80)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:117)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:61)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

In fact,I was download the spring source code and try fix it by edit source code.but I give up when spring haven't the problem but another apache class appear. So... is my config file wrong? or spring security share session doesn't like my way?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Bean
public ConfigureRedisAction configureRedisAction() {
    return ConfigureRedisAction.NO_OP;
}
```

Comment: Try adding this bean in your configuration.
I have this basic example you may check
https://github.com/Ravenloup/springboot-redis-session